# Proof that there is only one homomorphism from $\Bbb{Z}$ to $\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-writing

Could anyone help me (even just a start) to prove this ? Homomorphism (in rings) is a new notion for me and I have to confess that I am a bit lost, I don't know how to start.

Thanks in advance

Comment: That's not true. There are two distinct homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}_2$, for example: The zero map, and the map sending $1_{\mathbb{Z}}$ to $1_{\mathbb{Z}_2}$.

Comment: Hint: Think about $1$. | @T.Bongers OP probably means homomorphism of (unital) rings.

Comment: @anon Yes, you're probably right - thanks. OP: What do you mean by homomorphism? Are you considering these sets as groups, or rings?

Comment: I assume it's homomorphism of rings

Comment: @Jean-PaulTaphoureau People use different conventions when talking about rings; some people assume rings are unital and homomorphisms take $1$ to $1$, while others don't make these assumptions. So it's better to be explicit when asking around.

Answer (score 11):

If you are talking about unital ringhomomorphisms then for every ring $R$ (also $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$) there is exactly
one ringhomomorphims $\phi:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow R$. This because
the condition $\phi\left(1\right)=1_{R}$ determines $\phi$. Notice for instance 
that $\phi\left(n\right)=\phi\left(1+\cdots+1\right)=\phi\left(1\right)+\cdots+\phi\left(1\right)=1_{R}+\cdots+1_{R}$
for $n>0$.